# HTML Form in ie giving me the problem

Tags: html, forms

```
<form method='POST' action="some action">
        <span>
            <input id="foo" type="password" value="Enter Password"/>
                <input type="submit" class="go-btn" id="go-button" value="" />
        </span>
</form>
```

This is the HTML form I am using. In IE when I hit the enter key It will open a small window to which says to download something. But When I click the submit button It works fine.

BTW every thing is working fine with Mozilla and Chrome.

Comment: This has probably to do with the script specified in `action` than this form

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the given info.

Comment: Can you tell us the extension of your action.

Comment: @Pekka, I removed action and still same problem..

Comment: @Ankit: If I remove the form and it works.

Comment: Is your action class is in java or any other language?

Comment: @alis: if you are not uploading or downloading anything in form then try `method="get"`

Comment: @Alis ,Instead of submit buttton type ,try javascript for form submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a `name` to your password input:

```
<input id="foo" type="password" name="password" value="Enter Password" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 action="some action"
```

Is most likely your problem. Change this to the page that you want it to go to. (It's trying to send the data to the page "some action" which is causing it to break)

Comment: u can assume some action == "some.html"